# How important that, Field level assertion for the sales force lightening web application?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, salesforce, ui-automation, salesforce-lightning, webautomation

All,

I had this question during the test automation framework development. Further, I would like to understand from experts view as well.

How important to have a field level assertion compared with workflow level (Only end workflow result)? As the application is predominantly on the workflow based.

I am trying to learn the best practices asserting the salesforce application workflow, Also trying to understand the best way of reporting the sales force automation flows.

Thanks,

Ram